# piecemaker no shadow how to set variables

Tags: flash, 3d, slider

I am trying to integrate piecemaker in my webpage. I can easily display it with shadow but with noshadow i am helpless. I dont know what id or name or src i have to change to get the correct effect.... here is the code

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 AC_FL_RunContent(
  'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0',
  'width', '100%',
  'height', '100%',
  'src', 'piecemakerNoShadow',
  'quality', 'high',
  'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_de',
  'align', 'middle',
  'play', 'true',
  'loop', 'true',
  'scale', 'noscale',
  'wmode', 'window',
  'devicefont', 'false',
  'id', 'piecemaker',
  'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
  'name', 'piecemaker',
  'menu', 'true',
  'allowFullScreen', 'false',
  'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
  'movie', 'piecemaker',
  'salign', ''
  ); //end AC code
</script>
<noscript>
 <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="piecemaker" align="middle">
 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
 <param name="movie" value="piecemaker" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="scale" value="noscale" /><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent" /> <embed src="piecemakerNoShadow.swf" quality="high" scale="noscale" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" height="350" name="piecemaker" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_de" />
 </object>
</noscript>
```

this code is still showing it with shadow......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',

```
    'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',

    'movie', '**piecemakerNoShadow**',

    'salign', ''

    ); //end AC code
```

Change it piecemaker to piecemakerNoShadow.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML file under AC_FL_RunContent you must set "Movie" to piecemakerNoShadow
Like this: 
'movie', 'piecemakerNoShadow',

Comment: I changed all the names written in HTML code to piecemakerNoShadow and it is working